# Selenium Webdriver - how to click a value in a Wijmo combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, selenium-webdriver, wijmo

I have been unable to figure out how to do this. It seems that Wijmo comboboxes do not utilize the `input` tag.  I have tried using `.sendkeys()` and also using `new Select()`.

If I use `.sendKeys()` as follows, I can set the value of the combobox but this is not the same as 'clicking' the value. I need to be able to do this to enable another combobox to become enabled.

```
iDriver.findElement( By.id( "aircraft" ) )
    .sendKeys( aRegistrationCode );
```

I also tried using this, but it does not work either:

```
new Select( iDriver.findElement( By.id( "aircraft" ) ) )
    .selectByVisibleText( "REG000" );
```

@luksch - here is the snippet of html source:

```
<wij-combobox style="height:28px;width:240px;" id="aircraft" data-source="aircrafts" select="onRegCodeChange" drop-down-height="150" drop-down-width="200" > 
<data> 
<label bind="code"></label> 
<value bind="id"></value> 
</data> 
</wij-combobox>
```

@luksch - this combobox relies on the previous one to have a value selected for it be enabled:

```
<wij-combobox style="height:28px;width:240px;" id="addAtRiskReason"     data-source="atRiskReasons" select="onReasonChange" disabled="{{reasonDisabled}}" drop-down-height="150" drop-down-width="200" auto-complete="true"> 
<data> 
<label bind="name"></label> 
<value bind="id"></value> 
</data> 
</wij-combobox>
```

Comment: can you by any change post the html source?

Comment: @luksch - here is the snippet of html source:

<wij-combobox style="height:28px;width:240px;" id="aircraft" data-source="aircrafts" select="onRegCodeChange" drop-down-height="150" drop-down-width="200" >
                     <data>
                        <label bind="code"></label>
                        <value bind="id"></value>
                     </data>
                  </wij-combobox>

Comment: @luksch - this combobox relies on the previous one to have a value selected for it be enabled:                  
<wij-combobox style="height:28px;width:240px;" id="addAtRiskReason" data-source="atRiskReasons" select="onReasonChange" disabled="{{reasonDisabled}}" drop-down-height="150" drop-down-width="200" auto-complete="true">
                     <data>
                        <label bind="name"></label>
                        <value bind="id"></value>
                     </data>
                  </wij-combobox>

Comment: You can edit your own questions. It would be much easier to parse these if you could include the snippets in the question above.

Comment: Did the answer work out for you? If so, you might consider selecting it (by clicking the checkmark) so other people know what worked. And if not, it would be nice if you would comment on the answer so we know what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the selectedIndex property of WijComboBox using jQuery. Here is the link:
http://wijmo.com/docs/wijmo/#Wijmo~wijmo.combobox.wijcombobox.options~selectedIndex.html